# Fuzzy Logic function in R as in Matlab

Tags: r, matlab

Matlab fuzzy logic toolbox, presents the [Fuzzy Inference System Modeling.](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/fuzzy/mamdani-fuzzy-inference-systems.html). Is there an R-equivalent of all the toolbox or some R function like :

1. [readfis()](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/fuzzy/readfis.html) :Load Fuzzy Inference System from file
2. [evalfis](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/fuzzy/evalfis.html)() : Perform fuzzy inference calculations

to read and eval the fuzzy system within R?

Comment: downvoting without commenting is not constructive. Personally I don't see why the question is so donwvoted.

Comment: `library(sos); findFn('Fuzzy Inference System');`, I get the `frbs` package. I am not sure it can read the .fis files but it implements functionality and various algorithms to build and use fuzzy systems.

Answer (score 15):

Have a look at the [`sets package`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sets/)
It does all the things you expect from a fuzzy logic toolbox. It allows to specify your fuzzy membership functions, set up your fuzzy rules, do fuzzy inference and defuzzify.
The example in ?fuzzy_inference shows the restaurant example of the standard fuzzy logic textbook.
I highly recommend it.

```
## set universe
sets_options("universe", seq(from = 0, to = 25, by = 0.1))

## set up fuzzy variables
variables <-
set(service = fuzzy_partition(varnames = c(poor = 0, good = 5, excellent = 10), sd = 1.5),
food = fuzzy_variable(rancid = fuzzy_trapezoid(corners = c(-2, 0, 2, 4)),
                      delicious = fuzzy_trapezoid(corners = c(7, 9, 11, 13))),
tip = fuzzy_partition(varnames = c(cheap = 5, average = 12.5, generous = 20),
                      FUN = fuzzy_cone, radius = 5)
)

## set up rules
rules <-
set(
fuzzy_rule(service %is% poor || food %is% rancid, tip %is% cheap),
fuzzy_rule(service %is% good, tip %is% average),
fuzzy_rule(service %is% excellent || food %is% delicious, tip %is% generous)
)

## combine to a system
system <- fuzzy_system(variables, rules)
print(system)
plot(system) ## plots variables

## do inference
fi <- fuzzy_inference(system, list(service = 3, food = 8))

## plot resulting fuzzy set
plot(fi)

## defuzzify
gset_defuzzify(fi, "centroid")

## reset universe
sets_options("universe", NULL)
```

[image]

Comment: Which "standard fuzzy logic textbook" are you referring to?

Comment: I learned the restaurant example during a course for a master in artificial intelligence. Don't know exactly where the restaurant example came from originally but it is also an example appearing in the manuals of the fuzzy logic toolbox of Matlab. Well, it is just an example of fuzzy inference, there are dozen others in textbooks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the FuzzyToolkitUoN package. 
I believe it is developed by J. M. Garibaldi and others at the University of Nottingham.

The source code is available on his website:
http://ima.ac.uk/garibaldi

And work was published [here](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=6007743&abstractAccess=no&userType=inst).